# Why is zeroing a register via xorl faster than doing so via movl?

Tags: performance, assembly, hardware, cpu-registers

In [Programming from the Ground Up](https://www.academia.edu/1247519/Programming_from_the_Ground_Up) one reads that

> the XOR operation is faster than the loading operation, so many programmers use it to load a register with a zero. For example, the code
>
> ```
> movl $0, %eax
> ```
>
> is often replaced by
>
> ```
> xorl %eax, %eax
> ```

Now, since the book is old, a first question to ask would be whether this observation still applies today.

But in either case, the main question I have is *why* the two operations have (or had) different performance? What makes (or made) `xorl` be faster than `movl`?

I guess a hardware perspective is necessary to understand this?

Comment: This answer may provide info you may be interested in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33668295/3857942 . Note the mov immediate is a 5 byte instruction vs a 2 byte xor.

Comment: There was a recent comment or answer saying that on today's ARM processors it makes no difference, since both take a single clock cycle, but I can't find it. Obviously though, they don't have the `eax` register.

Comment: Modern x86-64 processors do not even need to execute `xor` in the main back-end parts (scheduler, execution units, etc.) : it can be filtered out before being scheduled so it does not reserve (much) backend resources. Basic `mov`s can be eliminated on some architectures too. SandyBridge processors (10 years old) was already capable of doing that like newer CPUs. `mov`s does not seems to be filtered out on Intel processors, though they are cheap (still more expensive than a `xor`). I guess this is the same on AMD Zen CPUs. Anyway both are *very* cheap on most CPUs.

Comment: `xor` zeroing is a rather x86-specific solution.  See this answer to take a broader view across instruction set architectures beyond x86 to other hardware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76933357/471129

Comment: The key thing is that `xor reg, reg` is a *zeroing idiom* recognised by the CPU.  This means that the register is cleared without any µops at all.  I've linked some relevant duplicated.  Also  check out [this article](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/).